# Why does .val() return 'undefined' for DOM element using jquery mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am experimenting with Jquery Mobile and i cant seem to see my mistake in why my Form elements return 'undefined'. I believe my mistake could be that my form has not been created when the onclick() function runs on my Member button. I know this code probably wont run due to missing css/js files in my HTML. Im hoping someone can quickly see my mistake and point it out.

js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {


});

function createMember() {
  var memberName = $("#memberName").val();
  var userName = $('#username').val();
  var pass = $('#password').val();

  var newMember = new submitMember(memberName, userName, pass);
  console.log(newMember);
}

function submitMember(Name, Username, Password) {
  this.Name = Name;
  this.UserName = Username;
  this.Password = Password;
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="C:\Users\ali\Desktop\Jquery Mobile\themes\CustomDarkBlue.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="C:\Users\ali\Desktop\Jquery Mobile\themes\jquery.mobile.icons.min.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.5.min.css"/>
        <script src="C:\Users\ali\Documents\jquery-2.0.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="C:\Users\ali\Desktop\Jquery Mobile\jquery.mobile.custom.js"></script>
        <script src="C:\Users\ali\Documents\Youtube_ContactsApp\js\VolunteerEfforts.js"></script>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"><!--the meta tag is to ensure that the view size remains 1px to 1 display pixel-->
    <!--class="ui-btn-active"-->
    </head>
        <title>Volunteer Effort</title>
            <body>
                <div data-role="navbar" data-grid="c">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#popupLoginInstitute" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-inline ui-icon-check ui-btn-icon-left ui-btn-a" data-transition="pop">Institution</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#popupLoginMember"  data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-inline ui-icon-check ui-btn-icon-left ui-btn-a" data-transition="pop">Member</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="ui-btn-active">Upcoming Events</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="ui-btn-active">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>

                        <!--<button type="submit" id="submit" onclick = "createMember()" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-b ui-btn-icon-left ui-icon-check">Sign Up</button>-->

                </div><!--/navbar-->

                <div data-role="popup" id="popupLoginInstitute" data-theme="a" class="ui-corner-all">
                    <form>
                        <div style="padding:10px 20px;">
                            <h3>Sign up as a new Institution</h3>
                            <label for="institution" class="ui-hidden-accessible">Username:</label>
                            <input type="text" name="user" id="institution" value="" placeholder="Institution Name" data-theme="a">
                            <label for="Address" class="ui-hidden-accessible">Institution Address:</label>
                            <input type="text" name="address" id="address" value="" placeholder="Address" data-theme="a">
                            <label for="username" class="ui-hidden-accessible">Username:</label>
                            <input type="text" name="user" id="username" value="" placeholder="Username" data-theme="a">
                            <label for="password" class="ui-hidden-accessible">Password:</label>
                            <input type="password" name="pass" id="password" value="" placeholder="Password" data-theme="a">
                            <label for="email" class="ui-hidden-accessible">Email:</label>
                            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" placeholder="Email" data-theme="a">
                            <label for="institutionSelect">Institution Selection:</label>
                            <select name="institutionSelect" id="institutionSelect" data-mini="true">
                                <option value="1">Religious Organization</option>
                                <option value="2">Food Bank</option>
                                <option value="3">Homeless Shelter</option>
                                <option value="4">Public School</option>
                            </select>
                            <button type="submit" id="submitInstitute" onclick = "createInstitute()" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-b ui-btn-icon-left ui-icon-check">Sign Up</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>

                <div data-role="popup" id="popupLoginMember" data-theme="a" class="ui-corner-all">
                    <form>
                        <div style="padding:10px 20px;">
                            <h3>Sign up as a new Member</h3>
                            <label for="member" >Full Name:</label>
                            <input type="text" name="member" id="memberName"  placeholder="Member's Full Name" data-theme="a">
                            <label for="username" class="ui-hidden-accessible">Username:</label>
                            <input type="text" name="user" id="username" placeholder="Username" data-theme="a">
                            <label for="password" class="ui-hidden-accessible">Password:</label>
                            <input type="password" name="pass" id="password" placeholder="Password" data-theme="a">
                            <button type="button" onclick="createMember()" id="submitMember" >Sign Up</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>  
            </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Those `var` declarations in your "ready" handler do not make sense. They have literally no effect on anything outside that handler function.

Comment: my bad, i was testing in jsfiddle and forgot remove that. I havfe made the correct edits

Comment: Do you come from another programming language than Javascript?  I'm on my phone, but I think your submit Member function is wrong, especially in regards to the this keyword. Could be wrong though. Good luck.

Comment: Um, that should not work on any device. The `function submitMember` is wrong.

Comment: There's also no need to use the new keyword. Since you aren't constructing a proper object anywhere.

Comment: Documentation on the `this` keyword [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)

Comment: Ok i understand i made a mistake on how the 'this' keyword works. However aside from that, even if i use Console.Log($('#...').val()) on my text fields, it continuously returns empty/undefined. Could this be that my Form elements are not created upon Document.ready?

Comment: memberName !== MemberName - i.e your jquery looks for #`memberName` - your element has id `MemberName`

Comment: @Jaromanda X, that was a good catch, and now i am getting a value from the member's Name field however my username and password still return empty. I removed the value=" " attribute from my html elements.

Comment: ID's in HTML **must** be unique - how does jquery know which `#password` field you want - jQuery isn't that smart :p - i.e. you have two inputs with id="password" and two inputs with id="username"

Comment: @Jaromanda X, dude i literally just caught that mistake!!! thank you so much for pointing that out. I have everything working now. Thanks you everyone!

Answer (score 2):

Your function should be setting the this.propertyName, not setting variables.

```js
function submitMember(name, userName, password) {
  this.name = name
  this.userName = userName;
  this.password = password
}

var user1 = new submitMember("A", "B", "C");
var user2 = new submitMember("FOO", "BAR", "WORLD");
console.log(user1);
console.log(user2);
```

Comment: For reference, does he need to call new? Not quite sure how that works, or if it's even needed.